# Speed up for each loop with variant array. Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I've got a worksheet that pulls a lot of data together from the rest of the workbook. My code then runs a 'for each' loop to remove any spaces in the data. The problem is i've got 60 instances of this code to run. From named ranges A1 to A60.
My question is can i speed this section of the code up by using arrays?
If i'm given pointers with this instance i can apply it to the other instances.
I've no experience with arrays hence my need for help.

[image]

Comment: Note that it's best to post your code as a code-block instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look into:

```
A1.Value = Application.Substitute(A1, " ", "")
```

Or:

```
A1.Replace what:=" ", Replacement:="", Lookat:=xlPart
```

Note that you can add more of the parameters of `Range.Replace()` to avoid any possible mishaps since this function will save and use settings of previous attempts using this function.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
Dim arr, r as long, v
'...
arr = A1.Value                 'get range values as array
for r = 1 to ubound(arr, 1)
    v = arr(r, 1)
    if len(v) > 0 Then arr(r, 1) = replace(v, " ", "")
next r
A1.Value = arr                 'return values to range
```